# VS Code opens every time I install or update application on Mac OS

Tags: macos

I have some kind of wrong file association in my Mac OS Catalina.

Every time I install or update an application, the system opens VS-Code. The application is also installed, but where do I find the association between apps and vs-code?

Comment: That's super weird to me. I didn't know that was possible! Have you tried resetting the LaunchServices database? `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/
LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user`

Comment: Fried: Tried now. But no change. Tried to install app from appstore and both xxx.appdownload and xxx.app was opened in VS Code.